# How to generate datetime mappings with Import Database Schema tool in IntelliJ?

Tags: mysql, datetime, jpa, intellij-idea, orm

I have MySQL table with datetime fiels. While generating mapping, it does not provide ability to select any `Datetime` class to generate, and simultaneously, does not allow to use `Object`.

[image]

How to fix?

**UPDATE**

I was able to enter `java.sql.Date` manually, which ability was not very obvious due to imperfections of GUI.

Comment: Does it allow Serializable? Why can't you use that?

Comment: RE: You're update. Did this solve your problem? If so, please add it as an answer and accept for future users. Also if there is a problem with the GUI/IntelliJ, please [raise an issue with Jetbrains](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues)